# Change references when copying sheet to multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code below to copy a worksheet from a source workbook to several hundred destination workbooks. The source worksheet contains references (in formula) to other worksheets in the source workbook; I would like to keep these references between sheets, but in the destination workbook. Can this code be modified to do this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim folder As String, filename As String
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination workbook

    Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "M:\Employee Information\Peter Young\Msc Project\1 - 181028 - Office First Floor\MacroCopy\"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add a line that does a find and replace of `"["&SourceWorkbook.name&"]!"` and replaces that with blank?

Comment: why not remove the "=" from all the cells, then move the sheet and replace the "=" when the sheet is in the destination?

Comment: @SolarMike because that way you'd need to record which cells have = and which ones dont, whereas you can easily remove the "[workbook.xlsx]!" part from every cell where it's found.

Comment: Solar Mike's suggestion is good, but you want to replace `=` with `'=`, then remove the apostrophe after the move, thus avoiding the overhead Fernando points out

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera works for me, I replace "=" with "xyxyxy" then replace it back... as all formulae become just a chunk of text...

Comment: Yeah but some of his formulas can have logical tests that involve "=", those would get changed too

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera they would also get changed back, I do this often, but your choice.

Comment: You're right and I'm dumb fam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Public Sub CopySheetToAllWorkbooksInFolder()

    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim destinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim folder As String, filename As String

    'Worksheet in active workbook to be copied as a new sheet to the destination workbook
    Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")

    'Folder containing the destination workbooks

    folder = "M:\Employee Information\Peter Young\Msc Project\1 - 181028 - Office First Floor\MacroCopy\"

    filename = Dir(folder & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)
    While Len(filename) <> 0
        Debug.Print folder & filename
        Set destinationWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folder & filename)
        sourceSheet.Copy before:=destinationWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        destinationWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:=sourceWorkbook.Name, NewName:=destinationWorkbook.Name, Type:=xlExcelLinks
        destinationWorkbook.Close True
        filename = Dir()  ' Get next matching file
    Wend
End Sub
```

I got this by going to Data>Edit Links with the destination workbook active and the Macro Recorder turned on, choosing "Change Source" and then browsing to the destination workbook.

Comment: Hello Doug, at which point in the code would I insert the line you suggest? I should probably have said, I have virtually no experience of this at all.

Comment: I understand. Right between copying the sheet and closing the workbook.

Comment: When you say I will have to assign the Activeworkbook to the sourceWorkbook variable at the beginning of the procedure; is that this line "Set sourceSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Edit")" and what would I need to change? Thanks, Peter

Comment: Okay, I've re-written your code to include my solution and the declarations and assignments (Dims and Sets) needed to make it work. I haven't actually run the code, so let me know if you get an error. Did you not write the original code? If you are going to keep coding, one thing is to learn to use the Macro Recorder.

Comment: Hi Doug, no I didn't write it, it was on a forum here, this is the first time I've had to do this. I am getting run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method. It is opening the first workbook and copying the sheet, but stopping there.

Comment: Woops, I left "Name" off of destinationWorkbook in the ChangeLink line. Please try it now.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you so much for your time. This is for my Msc project which is due in 2 weeks time; this has saved me hours of time data processing. Thanks again, Peter

Comment: You're welcome. It's amazing what a little VBA automation can do for horrible repetitive tasks. I hope the rest of your project goes well!